# Jenkins, run job in Docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, cloudbees

I am using Jenkins for my CI/CD and want to run most of my jobs in Docker.
I installed the plugin "CloudBees Docker Custom Build Environment Plugin" which allow me to run my jobs in a given docker as below:

[image]

When I check logs I see this:

```
docker exec --tty --user 996:994 890fd5fc166283923e61ea515d5f49a149e508c231281c39dc05e14d6ab43a09
```

The uid 996 is the jenkins user which does not even exist inside docker.
That is a problem because I can't do anything once inside docker (apt update, apt install)

Do you guys have any idea how, using that plugin, I can use the real user inside the docker ? (in this case the user must be "node")

Thanks

Comment: if you are using the official `jenkins` image, your container is running with `jenkins` user which does not have `sudo` right to perform admin task etc. So you need to build a customized jenkins image, and add your `apt update`, `apt install` steps before running `jenkins` server...

Comment: I am not running jenkins in Docker, I am running jenkins in EC2 on AWS. However my job are running inside Docker